# Access secret environment variables from kubernetes in nextjs app

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, next.js, environment-variables, keycloak

I'm trying to deploy a nextjs app to GCP with kubernetes. I'm trying to setup auth with nextAuth and keycloak provider. The issue I'm running into is that `KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET` and `KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET` can't be found, all of the other environment variables listed here show up under `process.env.XX` the two with secretKeyRefs come in undefined.

I have read in multiple places that they need to be available during build time for nextjs but I'm not sure how to set this up. We have several nodejs apps with this same deployment file and they are able to obtain the secrets.

This is what my `deployment.yaml` env section looks like.

Anyone have any experience setting this up?

I can't add the secrets to any local `env` files for security purposes.

```
env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: production
        - name: KEYCLOAK_URL
          value: "https://ourkeycloak/auth/"
        - name: NEXTAUTH_URL
          value: "https://nextauthpath/api/auth"
        - name: NEXTAUTH_SECRET
          value: "11234"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_REALM
          value: "ourrealm"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: vault_client
              key: CLIENT_SECRET
        - name: KEYCLOAK_CLIENTID
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: vault_client
              key: CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: the only problem is with client-side, right? you should be able to reach in serverside code?

Comment: @Yilmaz  I'm new to nextjs but the files where I'm trying to access `KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET` `KEYCLOAK_CLIENTID` are in `api/auth/[...nextauth].tsx` So I'm assuming this is meant as server side.

Comment: @Yilmaz forgot to mention and not sure if this could be a pain point, I'm exporting as `standalone`

Comment: in index.js 's `getServerSideProps` try to console.log one of the env variables